# Unicode и ASCII в Java

Tags: java, кодировка, char, символы

Как известно, Java использует таблицу Unicode для кодировки символов. Но при попытке привести символ к int, получается его значение этого символа из таблицы ASCII. Значит, что одновременно с Unicode, Java использует ещё и ASCII?

Comment: Первые 128 символов совпадают. Остальные символы юникода невозможно привести к ASCII.

Comment: Вот неплохая статья на Хабре про сложные отношения Java с кодировками: https://habr.com/post/315374/